# Cronjob running at wrong interval

Tags: cron

I have the following cron in my crontab:

```
0 5 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.mysite.com/crontask.php
```

From what I understand, this is to run at 5am every day and only once. However, I have noticed JUST today that it is running every 15 minutes from 5am. I did edit the crontab yesterday on a different cron job so i'm wondering if perhaps that has caused some sort of knock-on effect which make the system interpret the line above different when it 'installed'.

Running Centos.

As a responce to a query below. Here is a sample of the apache log (notice the incorrect time). I have masked the server IP address for security:

```
SERVERIPADDRESS - - [02/Mar/2011:05:15:04 +0000] "GET /crontask.php HTTP/1.0" 200 523 "-" "Wget/1.11.4 Red Hat modified" www.mysite.com
```

Here is the original:

```
SERVERIPADDRESS - - [02/Mar/2011:05:00:02 +0000] "GET /crontask.php HTTP/1.0" 200 523 "-" "Wget/1.11.4 Red Hat modified" www.mysite.com
```

Comment: How have you notived that the cron is running in a 15 minutes interval?

Comment: @Stony I checked out the apache access logs

Comment: If you found answers elsewhere, you can post and accept answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pablo's answer above makes great sense to me.  It would also be helpful to check what cron is logging about this job.  On an unmodified CentOS box, cron should log in `/var/log/cron`, so you should have some record of whether it's your job running at other intervals, or someone else's cron kicking this off.

If this file doesn't exist, your `syslog.conf` setup may be non-standard.  Assuming it's not, you should see an entry like

```
Mar  2 05:00:01 servername crond[xxxxx]: (root) CMD (wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.mysite.com/crontask.php)
```

Do you see that, and what other comparable entries do you see?

In addition, and please forgive the comment, but I notice that in your time on SF, you've asked six questions and accepted the answers for none.  Local etiquette is that you should accept the most-satisfactory answer for each question you ask, after a suitable period, by clicking on the tick outline next to the answer, and this helps drive the SF reputation system.  It may be that none of your questions has a satisfactory answer, in which case I apologise for mentioning this; but we all see a red logo by your userID saying "0% accept rate", and this may discourage others from answering your questions in future.  If you had a moment to revisit your earlier questions and review the answers, it would be helpful.

Comment: +1 for additional info and etiquette

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Oddly, the cron log says that the cron was only ran at 5am...so that conflicts with the apache access log (and the cron activity)...

Comment: I think it's fair to say that it conflicts with the apache access log, but I'm not sure you can be confident that cron was running it, if the cron logs don't say it was.  Could we see the apache logs?  We are starting to find reasons to suspect that other mechanisms are responsible for those.

Comment: @MadHatter thanks for the suggestion, I have added a line from the apache log.

Comment: Could you add the 0500 (correct) line for comparison?  If you mask the server address again, please confirm that they're the *same* masked address in each case (not "localhost" in one).

Comment: @MadHatter I have added the call for 5am. The IP addresses are the server. One thing that I have been reading up on is wget. Apparently it retries 20 times if a script gets a 404 or connection refused. I wonder if this would be the same case if it got a script timeout which could have possibly been the case?

Comment: That's certainly possible; it might be useful if you looked at the cron job output; turn off the `-q` flag, wait until tomorrow, and see what the 0500 job reports back.  The **date** on the output email will also be helpful; if it gets sent at 0503, then wget wasn't waiting around until 0515, but if it gets sent at 1135, that supports your hypothesis.

Comment: Our server admin seems to believe its the retry as well as the read-timeout is set to 900 seconds (15 min). But in this case, im not particularly bothered if the cron timeouts. So, does anyone know a way to telling wget not to retry at all?

Comment: `-t 1`, according to the manpage, will do one retry; 0 doesn't seem to be an option (it means "infinite", which isn't helpful).  Can you live with the one retry?

Comment: The solution has ended up being --tries=1 --read-timeout=1800 on wget.

Comment: Yaaay you!  Hopefully, knowing that it wasn't cron rerunning was helpful to you in finding the solution.  Thanks for the accept, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your cron looks correct to me.

I would guess there is another cron on your system that might be calling this.

Check /etc/crontab and /var/spool/cron

It may be there is a cron running as another user account.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked and everything looks fine there.

Comment: Have you tried restarting cron?  /etc/init.d/crond restart